# Removing a certain amount of rows in dataset in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a large dataset that I acquired from logging data on my computer and another dataset from a test bench on fuel cells.

The problem I'm facing is having the same amount of time in between the data, because my computer can log maximum of 5 Hz but the bench logs with 10 Hz.

So for an example then I have a dataset of 100x1 and another 50x1 both run on 10 sec, but I would like to delete the .(odd numbers) rows and leave the .(even numbers) rows on the 100x1 dataset.

Or if I would log on my computer at 2 Hz but the bench still on 10 Hz then I would like to remove the .1 .2 .3 .4 and .6 .7 .8 .9 regardless of what number is in front of it.

Comment: Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will greatly improve your chances of getting a useful answer if you do.

Comment: I was not sure how to make a code out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kkuilla mentioned, it is harder to answer without an example.

Here's a shot at what I think you are looking for:

```
x = rand(100,1);   %Generate sample data
oddsubset = x(1:2:100);   %Sample odd numbered points
evensubset = x(2:2:100);  %Sample even numbered points
twohertzsubset = x(1:5:100);  % Sample every 5th point
```

As mentioned in comments, any of these can also be assigned back to the original variable.  The reassignment in the examples above was done to support multiple cases more easily.

```
x = x(1:2:100);   % Keep only odd numbered points and overwrites the original variable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i think this is quite like i wanted but instead of deleting the points i just have to make a new array out of it, which i hadn't thought about.

Comment: To clarify, you don't have to make a new array, you can also assign it to itself, e.g. `x = x(1:2:100);`